# Installing kernel headers: not found?

Tags: kernel

On Debian, I need to build a driver with kernel headers.

```
$ uname -r
5.10.110
```

So I tried the easiest method:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.10.110
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

# This is added by me
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
```

1. How can I install kernel headers for `5.10.110` version?
2. Which other version might be a *safe bet* that complies with `5.10.110` and can be used for custom driver compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your kernel isn’t a Debian kernel, so you should install the kernel headers from wherever you got your kernel.
2. You might be able to get away with a newer 5.10 release, but you won’t be able to use the Debian-packaged kernel headers — they use a different ABI naming scheme (currently, 5.10.0-21), so you won’t be able to use them to build a kernel module which will load on your 5.10.110 kernel.

Unless you have a specific reason to use your 5.10.110 kernel, your best bet is to install the Debian kernel package and corresponding headers, and use that kernel instead:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-amd-64 linux-headers-amd64
```

(replacing `amd64` as appropriate).